# Find Missing Business dates from filenames

Tags: python

I have list of file names with business dates(bank holiday/ public holiday can also be businessday) since 20210212, some of the business dates are missing from them. Can someone advise how to get the missing business dates. Business dates are from Monday to Friday.

```
list = ['20210212d_filename0','20210215d_filename1','20210218d_filename3','20210217d_filename4']
```

```
output should be
20210216
```

Comment: Business dates often exclude holidays as well. How did you want to handle them?

Comment: What code have you written so far? We don't usually write code for you and look for some effort in your question.

Comment: grab first 8 letters.  sort alphabetically.  beyond that, you can either figure out the business days and check whether you have it or turn what you have into days of the week and find the gaps in the pattern.

Comment: we don't need to exclude holidays, I would say Monday to Friday

Comment: what about `20210213` and `20210214`? Where did they go?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import two modules `datetime` and [`holidays`](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/). Then use python date operations to check if date is a business day.

I have commented each line so you can easily understand the code.

```
import holidays
import datetime

filelist = ['20210212d_filename0','20210215d_filename1','20210218d_filename3','20210217d_filename4']

#sort the list in ascending order of filenames
#this gives the earliest date as first item
filelist.sort()

#get the earliest date and last date to iterate through
first_day = datetime.date(int(filelist[0][:4]),int(filelist[0][4:6]),int(filelist[0][6:8]))
last_day = datetime.date(int(filelist[-1][:4]),int(filelist[-1][4:6]),int(filelist[-1][6:8]))

#store all the US holidays in a variable to check
bizholidays = holidays.US()

#set next_day to first day
next_day = first_day
#iterate until the last date in the file list
while next_day <= last_day:
    #check if day is Mon thru Fri (0=Mon, 1=Tue... 4=Fri, 5=Sat, 6=Sun)
    #check if day is NOT part of business holidays
    #check if date string of YYYYMMDD is not part current list
    #if all of them satisfy, then date is missing in file list
    if next_day.weekday() < 5 and next_day not in bizholidays and \
    not any(next_day.strftime("%Y%m%d") in fname for fname in filelist):

        #date is not part of the file so print the date
        print (f'File for working day : {next_day} missing')

    #increment to next day using timedelta(1)
    next_day += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

The output of this is:

```
File for working day : 2021-02-16 missing
```

I don't know where you are located.

Here are some options for you to consider:

**India Holidays:**

```
bizholidays = holidays.IN() #India

print (bizholidays)

{datetime.date(2021, 1, 14): 'Makar Sankranti / Pongal', datetime.date(2021, 1, 26): 'Republic Day', datetime.date(2021, 8, 15): 'Independence Day', datetime.date(2021, 10, 2): 'Gandhi Jayanti', datetime.date(2021, 5, 1): 'Labour Day', datetime.date(2021, 12, 25): 'Christmas'}
```

**UK Holidays**

```
bizholidays = holidays.UK() #United Kingdom

print (bizholidays)

{datetime.date(2021, 1, 1): "New Year's Day", datetime.date(2021, 1, 2): 'New Year Holiday [Scotland]', datetime.date(2021, 1, 4): 'New Year Holiday [Scotland] (Observed)', datetime.date(2021, 3, 17): "St. Patrick's Day [Northern Ireland]", datetime.date(2021, 4, 2): 'Good Friday', datetime.date(2021, 4, 5): 'Easter Monday [England, Wales, Northern Ireland]', datetime.date(2021, 5, 3): 'May Day', datetime.date(2021, 5, 31): 'Spring Bank Holiday', datetime.date(2021, 7, 12): 'Battle of the Boyne [Northern Ireland]', datetime.date(2021, 8, 2): 'Summer Bank Holiday [Scotland]', datetime.date(2021, 8, 30): 'Late Summer Bank Holiday [England, Wales, Northern Ireland]', datetime.date(2021, 11, 30): "St. Andrew's Day [Scotland]", datetime.date(2021, 12, 25): 'Christmas Day', datetime.date(2021, 12, 27): 'Christmas Day (Observed)', datetime.date(2021, 12, 26): 'Boxing Day', datetime.date(2021, 12, 28): 'Boxing Day (Observed)'}
```

**Canada Holidays:**

```
bizholidays = holidays.CA() #Canada

print (bizholidays)

{datetime.date(2021, 1, 1): "New Year's Day", datetime.date(2021, 12, 31): "New Year's Day (Observed)", datetime.date(2021, 2, 15): 'Family Day', datetime.date(2021, 4, 2): 'Good Friday', datetime.date(2021, 5, 24): 'Victoria Day', datetime.date(2021, 7, 1): 'Canada Day', datetime.date(2021, 8, 2): 'Civic Holiday', datetime.date(2021, 9, 6): 'Labour Day', datetime.date(2021, 10, 11): 'Thanksgiving', datetime.date(2021, 12, 25): 'Christmas Day', datetime.date(2021, 12, 24): 'Christmas Day (Observed)', datetime.date(2021, 12, 27): 'Boxing Day (Observed)'}
```

You can give the 2 character country code to get the holidays and then check against it

If you don't find the business holidays in the default items and want to add specific days, you can do that too.

Let's say you want to add these 4 days to your list. You can do it as shown below:

```
#You can also add custom holidays and check for them
custom_holidays = holidays.US()
custom_holidays.append({"2021-02-14": "Valentines Day"})
custom_holidays.append(['2021-07-01', '2021-02-16','09/30/2021'])
```

And replace the code to check custom_holidays and it will work as normal.

```
if next_day.weekday() < 5 and next_day not in custom_holidays
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the logic is quite simple. First of all, you have extract the dates from those strings. Then convert those dates to datetime format. This will give the list of dates that are available. Now we have to find all the missing dates between these dates which lies from `Monday to Friday`.

We can list all the dates from start date to end date with the help of `pd.date_range()` function. After getting all the lists of dates, we can check whether those dates are in `Monday to Friday` or not. If such then we can append it to final list which consist of only dates that are not weekdays.

If any of the date above is not present in the initial list, we can append it to missing date list.

Full code

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

list1 = ['20210212d_filename0','20210215d_filename1','20210218d_filename3','20210217d_filename4']

list2 = [s[:8] for s in list1]  #taking the dates from strings

list3 = []
for e in list2:
  e = e[:4]+"-"+e[4:6]+"-"+e[6:8] #formating the string to yyyy-mm-dd
  list3.append(e)

list4 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(e, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for e in list3] #converting strings to dates

#getting all the dates from first date to last
all_dates = pd.date_range(list4[0],list4[-1]-timedelta(days=1),freq='d').date.tolist() 

final_list=[]
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thrusday', 'Friday']
for date in all_dates:
  #append only if they are between monday to friday
  if date.strftime('%A') in days:
    final_list.append(str(date))

final_absent_dates = []
for date in final_list:
  if date not in list3: #if dates are not present in list3
    final_absent_dates.append(date)

final_absent_dates= [e[:4]+e[5:7]+e[8:10] for e in final_absent_dates] #formatting date to string

final_absent_dates

#>>>output = ['20210216']
```